# Why is per country cap for employment based immigration gcs not illegal?

Tags: united-states, employment, us-constitution, immigration, minor

I have a minor son who is a legal us citizen but I am on h1b with valid I-140 for the last 8 years. In case of job loss where I have to leave the usa, he will have to go thru the tough choice of either to leave the usa (and go back to a India and suffer the consequesnces) or the stay at a foster home in usa without his parents. This is causing great emotional trauma and impacts access to good us facilities much needed by all citizens. This per country cap is **disparately impacting** minor us citizens whose parents are from india or china.

The whole argument for this law is that it promotes diversity but supreme court has already adjugated that **equal protection > diversity** in harvard case, especially when it impacts its citizen directly even to get basic amenities (if he has to go to india in order to be with his to his parents). So how is this law not illegal?

Comment: You are on the Law StackExchange, so it should be based on legal arguments. But you are just making a bunch of emotional or policy arguments, e.g. that it's unfair or causes suffering, etc. Can you point to a section of law or the Constitution, that you propose would make it illegal?

Comment: I propose it is illegal because of 14th amendment equal protection of all under the law. The disparate impact it is causing the us citizens of minors of Indian or Chinese parents on the grounds of diversity is challengeable, because of similar ruling in sffa vs Harvard by supreme court.

Answer (score 2):

It is not illegal because no law has made it illegal. Congress has passed various laws prohibiting discrimination, but each such law is rather specific. Congress has passed no law which across the board forbids government actions that discriminate on the bases of national origin. Congress *has* passed numerous laws that actually do so, viz. the [Immigration and Nationality Act](https://www.uscis.gov/laws-and-policy/legislation/immigration-and-nationality-act), where non-citizens have to have a visa to enter, unless they are LPRs or Canadian. Congress *could* repeal INA, the reason why it won't is political, not legal. Non-prohibited discrimination is entirely legal (by definition).

Comment: The argument is about disparately impacting minor us citizens of indians and chinese parents and not about how it impacts the non-citizens. It does not affect non-citizens because they well informed about the laws before they chose to come in, but minor citizens (minors who had no say in this) should not be impacted.

Comment: @GBasu, no sane immigration policy would allow parents to move themselves to the front of the immigration line via having children.  The parents put the child in this position, not the US government.

Comment: Does not matter, how they achieved here they are us citizens now and cannot not be discriminated against. Also, this is not about parents but childrens rights to have a good life.

Comment: @GBasu, you are making some type of moral argument, not a legal one.  There is no law or legal right for a citizen child to have their alien parents remain in the country. Your proposal to the contrary would be a workaround to immigration policy, and would mean that anyone who wanted to immigrate just needed to have a child in the country.

Comment: @TigerGuy I am making a legal argument against affirmative action for immigration as it is impacting minors with indian parents disparately  as it is against the equal protection act. Diversity cannot be a ground for denying equal protection to minors.

Comment: @TigerGuy I am not asking for child's right to have their alien parents remain in the country, what i am asking is that they shouldn't be disparately impacted from children of parents immigrating from other countries.

Comment: @GBasu you seem to think that people of all countries should have the same right to immigrate, or more specifically that the H1B regs should apply to everyone?  Well, USA legislatures disagree, and there is no enumerated right to immigrate.

Comment: @TigerGuy - There is enumerated right for equal protection under the law. isn't it.